# Why are the execution plans for these two queries so different?

Tags: sql-server

I have a database with the following existing table in it:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[sites]
(
    [site_id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [description] [nvarchar](80) NOT NULL,
    [parent_id] [uniqueidentifier] NULL,
    [domain_id] [int] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_sites] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED ( site_id] ASC
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[sites] WITH CHECK 
  ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_sites_sites] 
  FOREIGN KEY([parent_id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[sites] ([site_id])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[sites] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_sites_sites]
```

I have added another table that looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[site_map]
(
    [force_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [source_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [camera_id] [int] NOT NULL,
    [site_id] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_site_map] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
        ([force_id] ASC, [source_id] ASC, [camera_id] ASC)
)

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[site_map] WITH CHECK 
  ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_site_map_sites] 
  FOREIGN KEY([site_id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[sites] ([site_id])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[site_map] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_site_map_sites]
```

Now, when I execute this query:

```
SELECT 
    m.[site_id], c.[description], s.[site_id] AS ReaderId, s.[domain_id]
FROM 
    [dbo].[site_map] AS m
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [dbo].[sites] AS c ON m.[site_id] = c.[site_id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    [dbo].[sites] AS s ON c.[parent_id] = s.[site_id]
WHERE 
    [force_id] = @forceId 
    AND [source_id] = @sourceid 
    AND [camera_id] = @cameraId
```

I get a query plan that executes two nested loops.  But, when I change the query so it reads like this:

```
SELECT 
    m.[site_id], c.[description], s.[site_id] AS ReaderId, s.[domain_d]
FROM 
    [dbo].[site_map] AS m
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[sites] AS c ON m.[site_id] = c.[site_id]
INNER JOIN 
    [dbo].[sites] AS s ON c.[parent_id] = s.[site_id]
WHERE 
    [force_id] = @forceId 
    AND [source_id] = @sourceid 
    AND [camera_id] = @cameraId
```

The query plan executes four nested loops! The only thing that changed was the type of join. Why are the query plans so different?

Comment: You should also include the query plans. That usually helps to figure out what's happening

Answer (score 0):

Are you actually noticing a performance difference?

My guess is that the INNER JOINs are still more efficient.  Take a look at the "Number of executions" of each nested loop operation in the query plan.  I'm guessing that the LEFT JOINS have *naive nested loop* operations, or at least a less efficient scan input, and that the INNER JOINs have less executions and may not be a full cartesian loop of left side x right side, they may only be executing once per row in the left side.  Hard to say without seeing the query plan.

I would SET STATISTICS IO ON, flush your caches and see how many logical reads you get with each operation and see what the difference looks like.

Comment: While I can do this, I only have about 3 rows of data in the map table and a dozen or so in the sites table to test with.  I suspect there will be thousands of rows in both tables, but I don't know exactly how many.  Will the query plans I generate be useful in that case?

Comment: No, sadly they won't be.  SQL Server will often choose dramatically different query plans when tables have tiny amounts of data - ignoring indexes and using scans, etc.  Try to insert some test data if you can to get it closer to your estimated workloads

Answer (score 0):

(On a SQL Server Compact DB, which might behave differently):

```
SELECT m.[site_id], c.[description], s.[site_id] AS ReaderId, s.[domain_id]
FROM [site_map] AS m
LEFT OUTER JOIN [sites] AS c ON m.[site_id] = c.[site_id]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [sites] AS s ON c.[parent_id] = s.[site_id]
WHERE [force_id] = 1 AND [source_id] = 1 AND [camera_id] = 1
```

[image: Left Outer Join Estimated Execution Plan]

```
SELECT m.[site_id], c.[description], s.[site_id] AS ReaderId, s.[domain_id]
FROM [site_map] AS m
INNER JOIN [sites] AS c ON m.[site_id] = c.[site_id]
INNER JOIN [sites] AS s ON c.[parent_id] = s.[site_id]
WHERE [force_id] = 1 AND [source_id] = 1 AND [camera_id] = 1
```

[image: Inner Join Estimated Execution Plan]

Sorry, but I don't see four loops in the second execution plan. If you provide screen shots of your execution plans, it would be helpful.

Comment: That's weird.  Your query plans are exactly opposite of what I see.  That is, the query plan you posted for the LEFT OUTER JOIN is what I see for the INNER JOIN, and vice-versa.

Comment: I also thought it strange that INNER joins would favor table scans over the LEFT OUTER JOINs. I checked twice to make sure I didn't mix the query plans. This difference might be because the databases are slightly different versions (I'm on SQL CE while you're either on SQL licensed or SQL Express). I also verified that the constraints and keys were exactly the same in definition, though the PK of the mapping table was built without defining its name.